# panel with false visiblity vs loading remote content

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, panel

If i have multiple content that will be displayed after some selection and a click event . For example, if I select item 1 only content 1 is displayed, and if i select item 3 only content 3 is displayed .

Which is better (with regard to page load time):

1) put each content in a separate panel (with visibility = false) . and if it is selected, visibility is set to true .

2) put each content in a remote html page, and load it by jquery ajax method if selected .

Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 would result in a slower initial page load, but no more requests thereafter.

Option 2 would result in a faster initial page load, but also in consecutive page loads when you change panels.

There is actually a 3rd option where you would initially only load panel 1 and than load the other panels in the background with AJAX.

Comment: for option 1, why page load will be slower if only one panel will be loaded (as far as i know visible = false means it will not be load) .

Comment: Why wouldn't something that is not visible not be loaded?

Comment: I meant by visible = false the asp control property . and when you view page source, panels will visible = false are not loaded .

Comment: ah, ok, thought you we're talking about the CSS property. Wouldn't know how to set an ASP property client-side, though. But then again, I don't know ASP.

Answer (score 0):

Loading by ajax method is scalable, you don't want to hide 100+ items, it makes the page slower.
But then again, if there are only a few items, you could go for the first option since it doesn't put as much load on the server.

Comment: I have a really large number of items . see my reply to Ewout please .

Comment: Then option 2 is better. Whether to return HTML or have a template on the page and return JSON would be another question. And then you could cache the json if that makes sense.

Comment: So, is the case will be different if i meant by visible the asp control property ?

Comment: yep, never tried asp.net except for the mvc-variant. Not sure what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Your terms need to be clarified.

- You are making an asp.net control invisible, and not setting it's css property to invisible.  If that is the case, then it really doesn't matter where you store the data. You're still going to have to make a postback (either full or partial) to get the data since you are just rendering the bare minimum. (no hidden panels with information)
- When you say 'remote' html page, do you just mean you're storing the content in a different file on the same server, or do you mean the content is on a remote server? This is the only thing that would affect load time for you.  If it is on a remote server, then it will take longer. If it is on another file, it will not be much different than putting that information in the same file.

Comment: OK . For option 1: the postback is not the problem . I meant that will setting a large number of panels visibility to false (asp control property) affect page load time . or not (because panels with visible = false means it will not be loaded) is this true ? For option 2: I meant same server different file . I believe there is a difference, because only one file (html content) will be loaded a time based on selection . that was my point .

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  I kept on thinking of load time as render time.  The render time will be the same in any method since you are only rendering visible items, but the load time will be cut down if you selectively load.  Where you selectively load, however, makes very little difference if it is on the same server.  A simple solution would be to let your page run it's logic, then on the page_prerender state, load up the content for only the visible elements.  This way you can just use an updatepanel instead of the jquery route.